# Finding $S$, $D$, and $S^{-1}$ such that $A = SDS^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}18&12\\-40&-26\end{bmatrix}$Find $S$, $D$, and $S^{-1}$ such that $A = SDS^{-1}$

So I did $\det(A-\lambda I)$ to get the char. poly. eqn. and got eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = -6, \lambda_2 = -2$ then:

I  did $(A - \lambda_1 I)$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}1&1/2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and similarly $(A - \lambda_2 I)$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}1&3/5\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

so I got $S = \begin{bmatrix}1/2&3/5\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$, $D = \begin{bmatrix}-6&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}$, and $S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}-10&6\\10&-5\end{bmatrix}$ but my answer is incorrect for some reason

Comment: oh boy...diagonalization. A word still not recognized by WORD....

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: Never mind. But what did you get for your eigenvectors?

Comment: The columns of S should be eigenvectors for A.

Comment: @Yusha Sorry, but I found an eigenvector of $\lambda=-2$ to be $<3,-5>$ , you can use fractions but one entry is negative. (I did not check the other eigenvector yet)

Comment: My eigenvectors are the corresponding columns in $A$ as @user84413 mentioned

Comment: @Yusha Yes, however in the one I calculated, you are off by a negative...

Comment: @imranfat Which entry?

Comment: @Yusha  You put in the second column of $S$ the values $3/5$ and $1$. They are both positive. That is not correct. I have $3/5$ and $-1$

Comment: how is that possible? I have $A - \lambda_2 I = A + 2I = \begin{bmatrix}20&12\\-40&-24\end{bmatrix}$ ~ $\begin{bmatrix}10&6\\-10&-6\end{bmatrix}$ ~ $\begin{bmatrix}1&3/5\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, from the first row $10$ and $6$ it follows $10x+6y=0$ from which follows $10x=-6y$ or $5x=-3y$ and the sign change is thus clear. It seems like, upon further inspection, that you made the same mistake for the other eigenvector as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
18 & 12 \\
-40 & -26
\end{array}\right]$ is
$$
\chi_A(t)=\det(tI-A)=\det\left[\begin{array}{rr}
t - 18 & -12 \\
40 & t + 26
\end{array}\right]=t^{2} + 8t + 12=(t + 2) \cdot (t + 6)
$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are thus $\lambda=-2$ and $\mu=-6$.

To compute a basis of $E_\lambda$, note that
$$
E_\lambda=\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null(\lambda I-A)
=\Null\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-20 & -12 \\
40 & 24
\end{array}\right]\overset{\circledast}{=}\Null\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & \frac{3}{5} \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\left\{
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
3 \\ -5
\end{array}\right]
\right\}
$$
where the equality marked $\circledast$ comes from row-reducing.
So, one of the columns of $S$ should be a nonzero scalar multiple of $\left[\begin{array}{rr}
3 \\ -5
\end{array}\right]
$.

To compute a basis of $E_\mu$, note that
$$
E_\mu=\Null(\mu I-A)=\Null
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-24 & -12 \\
40 & 20
\end{array}\right]\overset{\circledast}{=}
\Null
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]=\Span\left\{
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 \\ -2
\end{array}\right]\right\}
$$
So the other column of $S$ should be a nonzero scalar multiple of $\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 \\ -2
\end{array}\right]$.

Putting this together, we have $A=SDS^{-1}$ where
\begin{align*}
D &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
\color{red}{-2} & 0 \\
 0 & \color{blue}{-6}
\end{array}\right] &
S &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
\color{red}{3} & \color{blue}{1}\\ \color{red}{-5} & \color{blue}{-2}
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

Comment: Now it is saying my $S^{-1}$ is incorrect. But how? I got $S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\-5&3\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Yusha Should be a $-3$.

Comment: god i hate this class. thanks

Comment: @Yusha Brians eigenvectors are for sure correct. Now when you type in your TI calculator $SDS^{-1}$, does that produce your given matrix $A$? That should be a check you ought to do first before putting an answer in the system

Comment: We aren't allowed to use calculators at all lol @imranfat

Comment: @Yusha Learn to like it! Linear algebra is a great subject but it takes some patience at first!

Comment: @Yusha My other advice is then to take the algebra real SLOW to avoid silly mistakes and also, when you pick your eigenvectors, for heaven's sake, avoid fractions, but take integer entries like Brian also did

Comment: I actually like Linear Algebra I'm just in a summer course and its flying and we don't get a chance to really learn anything @BrianFitzpatrick

Comment: @Yusha That's the problem with summer courses. You are cramming the material without discovering its beauties. It doesn't allow you much to learn about the possibilities Linear has to offer. Don;t know what your academic future is but I very often tell my students to avoid taking any math over the summer (and certainly not Calc)unless you are a retaker. You just indicated the reason why...